# Why is conditional formatting manager getting messy?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, rules

Not really a problem, but I wonder.. Why is it that if you make one rule in Excel, for the entire sheet,
it automaticly changes?

I have just one rule: If column I contains '0000' then the B:W gets a color.
=(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("0000";$I10))) Applies to $B10:$W10

When I open the manager a few days later I have 30 lines, all with this formula, but different types of values in "applies to"
Some line just apply to $Y$18 and another line to $B$18:$W$18

Why does this happen?
Everything still works perfectly, but it is weird right?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you copy an range with conditional formatting. The formatting is also copied at that point.

[image]

Comment: Aha this make sense! Thanks!